# How to name an Instance of an NSObject, from an NSString or UITextField (to add to NSMutableArray)

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

When I add an instance of my NSObject class, as an additional item, to my NSMutableArray, it adds it as the same name each time. (the @properties inside the NSObject are different).

I want to be able to name the instances (of the NSObject Class) something different, so that when they get added to the NSMutableArray, each time (that the user hits the add button), they are differently named items. How can I name the instances something different, based on an NSString / UITextfield input? Many thanks.

Additional info :

FirstViewCont.h **_** `@property ABDataNSO *ABDataNSOItem;`    // Data Storage 'toDoItem'

FirstViewCont.m **_** `@synthesize ABDataNSOItem;`

// In my view controller.m file, I Alloc & Init my instance of 'ABDataNSO' NSObject class, which has some user inputted @properties in it.

```
 ABDataNSOItem = [[ABDataNSO alloc] init];
```

// Then I add that instance of my NSObject, to my NSMutableArray, when the user hits a button to add/ save their details.

```
[self.ABMutableTempArray addObject:ABDataNSOItem];
```

This outputs ..

> NSLog(@"sssssssssss%@", self.ABMutableTempArray);
>
> 2014-09-06 00:37:15.844 ABAppMini011[2687:60b] All of the items in my
>   Array are called ABDataNSO. (
>
> ```
> "ABDataNSO: 0x8e321e0",
>
> "ABDataNSO: 0x8cc9c00",
>
> "ABDataNSO: 0x8c829f0"
> ```

For example, I would rather the items be called “ABDataNSORace1, ABDataNSORace2, ABDataNSORace3.” Any suggestions?

Comment: WHY? why you need the names like that when the object name is `ABDataNSO`? And what is the purpose of creating such objects?You only defined an object.If this logic supposed to work , there must be class defenition for this individual objects also.right?

Comment: I just want to be able to differentiate and identify those items, because they hold different @properties (information inside them). And list the array items (in a table).

Comment: Objects don't have names, unless you declare a field in the object and make it the name field.

Comment: What's being displayed by NSLog is the *description* of the object.  If it's your class you can override *description* to return whatever you want.  Most useful is some representation of the data contained therein, similar to what NSArray displays when you invoke its *description* method (by NSLogging it).

Answer (score 0):

Those strings are devised by way of the `NSObject` method `description`. There are a couple ways you could manipulate that:

- Override `description` in your `ABDataNSO` class so that you can `setDescription:(NSString*)` or similar per instance.
- Either use this `setDescription:` every time you add to your `NSMutableArray`, OR
- Subclass `NSMutableArray` for your implementation, and add an `addObject: withDescription` or something like that, and keep up with the description of each object for use in your own overridden `description` method. I don't like this approach though.

Comment: Thanks Gutblender. Appreciated. That can be my project, for the next 2 weeks :-).

Comment: Does that mean this is too hard to implement?